# Multiple select not showing the complete list

Tags: css, html

I have a div inside which there is a multiple select list. Div has a fixed height and overflow-y : scroll. When the list has huge values to be displayed, the scrollbar on div is not able to go down after a certain point . However if I try to use mouse down - it is able to scroll down.

Please refer to the markup :

```
<div id="selectScroll_div" style="margin:-58px 0px 0px 0px">
   <select name="lcLhs" id="lcLhs" size="1480" multiple="multiple">
    <option>.....</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

In my css I have:

```
#selectScroll_div {
width: 180px;
height: 140px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Here is the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Vqh/3/

Comment: like @KarthickKumarGanesh mentioned, fiddle your code. http://jsfiddle.net/
or if it is possible, more details are required on the coding.

Comment: Here is the fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Vqh/3/

Comment: Hi @aasthaC. Take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 sets of scroll bars. One on your `div` and one on your `select`. You need to get rid of the need for a scroll bar on your select box.

The reason for the scroll bar on your `select` is it's `size` value is less than the amount of options inside it. You need to set size to be equal to the amount of options inside the select (in your example this is 1515).

**HTML**

```
<div id="selectScroll_div">
    <select name="lcLhs" id="lcLhs" size="1515" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="699803">AIHI_TREND - this is a very long option</option>
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#selectScroll_div {
    width: 180px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Vqh/6/)**

Comment: This functionality looses the ability to scroll in x direction. The multiple list can contain names bigger than the view window

Comment: The value of size was dynamically generated. But in some cases the generated value of size was less. Working now @3dgoo

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the value of size. You have assigned 1480. Please change it to  7 or less than 7 or you can just remove size from select statement That is the reason. It wont show the selected value till the time it completes its size , which according to your code is 1480. Just change its value and execute again. Good luck

Comment: @3dgoo has also done the same in his code. He has just removed the value of size from your code and its working. And 3dgoo your code is working but your explanation is not accurate. aastha C do reply if it works.

Comment: The div is not scrolling. The select element is scrolling but for that we need to scroll in x direction to find the scrollbar